# Skipping colors in colormap when value is NaN in Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'd like a plot a scatter graph of values (y-axis) against dates (x-axis). I'd like to change the color of the point according to month of the year. i.e. each month has a unique color. I'd ideally like to take the colors from a colormap e.g. Viridis.

I have some example data as follows:

```
# example data
mydata = np.array([0.85405058, 0.78228784, np.nan, 0.72828138, 0.73757833, 0.69303712, 0.5730553,  0.57644895]) 
dates_list = [datetime.date(2017, 1, 5), datetime.date(2017, 5, 22), 
datetime.date(2017, 6, 14), datetime.date(2017, 8, 17), datetime.date(2017, 9, 27), datetime.date(2017, 10, 6), datetime.date(2017, 11, 23), datetime.date(2017, 12, 28)] 
months_list= [1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

# plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.scatter(dates_list,mydata,s=30,c=months_list,cmap='viridis')
```

If I do this, then it works if there are no missing values, but if there are NaNs (which my data has), then the colors get shifted out of alignment and are no longer unique to a particular month. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to assign a unique color to each month?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can you provide an example where the problem is actually apparent? If I run your code I get a different color for each month as expected

Comment: You could set `vmin` to 1 and `vmax` to 12 as arguments in the `ax.scatter` line.  https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html.  This will set the max and min values for the colormap.  What do you want to happen when there is a NaN?

Comment: The first comment is right, without an example that actually shows the problem, it's hard to understand. (Mind that your code only has unique month, so you will have unique colors anyways.) Also consider specifying your matplotlib version to be able to reproduce the problem once you have updated the code.

Comment: You're right - turns out the problem wasn't in the plotting but in the data I sent to Matplotlib. I apologize for asking a dumb question.